# Scroll only the table body (without the header)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-table

I have a table in which I can scroll through data (if the list is large). However, in most tables, the scroll extends to both the header and the body. And in my table, I would like only the body to be scrolled.

For this in the body I use

```
 display: block !important;
 overflow: scroll;
 table-layout: auto;
 max-height: 300px;
```

But there is a problem, that the body of the table is arranged in one column.

Tell me how can I avoid this problem?

In my code to build the table, I use the react-table-library library (https://react-table-library.com/?path=/story/getting-started-installation--page)

Comment: If you are ok with changing library try [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) to fulfil your requirement. also see [codesandbox with table body scrollable](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-fixed-header-vertical-scroll-w8bjn?file=/package.json:164-175)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `thead { position: sticky; }`.
Something like this: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-night-lcq49k?file=/src/App.tsx)